# findall() behaviour (python 2.7)

Tags: python, findall

Suppose I have the following string:

```
"<p>Hello</p>NOT<p>World</p>"
```

and i want to extract the words `Hello` and `World`

I created the following script for the job

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

string = "<p>Hello</p>NOT<p>World</p>"
match = re.findall(r"(<p>[\w\W]+</p>)", string)

print match
```

I'm not particularly interested in stripping < p> and < /p> so I never bothered doing it within the script.

The interpreter prints

```
['<p>Hello</p>NOT<p>World</p>']
```

so it obviously sees the first < p> and the last < /p> while disregarding the in between tags. Shouldn't `findall()` return all three sets of matching strings though? (the string it prints, and the two words).

And if it shouldn't, how can i alter the code to do so?

PS: This is for a project and I found an alternative way to do what i needed to, so this is for educational reasons I guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you get the entire contents in a single match is because `[\w\W]+` will match *as many* things as it can (including all of your `<p>` and `</p>` tags). To prevent this, you want to use the non-greedy version by appending a `?`.

```
match = re.findall(r"(<p>[\w\W]+?</p>)", string)
# ['<p>Hello</p>', '<p>World</p>']
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `*?`, `+?`, `??`
>   The `'*'`, `'+'`, and `'?'` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against `<a> b <c>`, it will match the entire string, and not just `<a>`. Adding `?` after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using the RE `<.*?>` will match only `<a>`.

If you don't want the `<p>` and `</p>` tags in the result, you will want to use look-ahead and look behind assertions to not include them in the result.

```
match = re.findall(r"((?<=<p>)\w+?(?=</p>))", string)
# ['Hello', 'World']
```

As a side note though, if you are trying to parse HTML or XML with regular expressions, it is preferable to use a library such as [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is intended for parsing HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I overlooked that part of REs

Comment: I will look into BeautifulSoup as well, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: +1 for BeautifulSoup (or similar). HTML is not a regular language, so regular expressions are not a good tool for parsing them. It will be much easier to just use a library that understands HTML.